Use of the word "tongue" to refer to a specific language
One of the meanings of the word "tongue" is "language". The word is still in use in certain expressions ("mother tongue" being one of them), and I know that in the past, it was used to refer to the classical languages. However, I have never seen it used as a substitute for "language" when referring to a specific language - for example, today, one would say "the English language" and not "the English tongue".
When did "tongue" stop being used in such instances?

English tongue is still used, though it is less common than in the past:  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=English+tongue&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Here's someone in 2011 calling English a "mongrel tongue", and you can find lots of "common tongue", "shared tongue", etc. There's something a bit poetic, twee, or old-fashioned about "tongue" compared to "language", but it's still used.

It may be relevant that the word "language" comes from the Latin "lingua", which meant tongue.

While "tongue" has roots in Old English and Germanic. So I suspect the switch from tongue to language happened as a result of the Norman invasion of Britain, when the aristocracy adopted French vocabulary.

It's still a literary usage: << Elven-tongue:
Any of the languages of the Elves [... Quenya; Sindarin ... ] >> [The Encyclopedia of Arda]

@Gio - A lot of the 'modern' books referring to 'the English tongue' appear to be reprints of works several centuries old.

Whether one would use 'English language' or 'English tongue' depends entirely on context.
'Tongue' is a little old fashioned and I suggest it's not even close to being archaic; not yet, anyway.
